# redirect input standard MATLAB

Tags: matlab

From Matlab I call a system command and this command will ask to enter **yes** or **no**. How could I redirect to input ?

I've tried:

```
myCmd = fullfile('control','bin','launch');
cmd = system(myCmd);
```

=> this will ask following message to enter yes /nos (prompt)

so I've tried

```
cmd = system([myCmd ,' < ','yes'])
```

but this is not working.

Comment: Most CLI commands use the format `myCmd /y` (Windows/DOS) or `myCmd -y` (Mac/Linux) so I have a strong suspicion you're just calling the command incorrectly.

Comment: Also, "is not working"; can you be a bit more specific? What error(s) do you get?

Comment: If the system command is asking for user input from the middle of the code, I suspect this is not possible.  If you run `system([myCommand '&'])` then you will at least get a system window to interact with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input` function provided in matlab. `result = input(prompt)` displays the prompt string on the screen, waits for input from the keyboard. More about it [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/input.html#btuddxv-1). Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

To request a simple text response that requires no evaluation.

```
prompt = 'Do you want more? Y/N [Y]: ';
str = input(prompt,'s');
if isempty(str)
    str = 'Y';
end
```